# Ionic 3 : Images file does not load in devices

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I couldnt figure out what went wrong. When i try `ionic serve` everthings loads properly. But when I try running it on android device none of the image loads and instead shows an error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` None of the image loads properly.

my scss file

```
.bg-image{
        background-image: url('../../assets/imgs/bgimage.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 200%;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        position: absolute;
```

my html file

```
<div class="bg-image">
.
.
</div>
```

unable to figure out please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hello,

```
    .bg-image{
      background-image: url('../assets/imgs/bgimage.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 200%;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      position: absolute;
    }
```

> When addressing images from your .ts files, use ../assets relative
>   path because we have to get out of the build directory first. When
>   addressing the image from your .html files, use assets relative path,
>   because in the final apk file all HTML are merged into one single file
>   called index.html which is placed next to the assets directory and
>   there is no need to go up one level before reaching assets.

Add your images to **src/assets/imgs** directory

Set image path in HTML like

```
<img src="assets/imgs/bgimage.png">
```

Set image path in SCSS like

```
background-image: url(../assets/imgs/bgimage.png);
```

It will work browser, emulator and build

hope that help you :)

Comment: unable to figure out somewhere the image with `'../assets/imgs/bgimage.png'` is shown and somewhere with `'assets/imgs/bgimage.png'`

Comment: is this happening because of android studio update? cause yesterday it was working fine even after released apk and since i updated Android studio it started causing error :(

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the path keep images in main www/assets/img folder and then set

```
background-image: url('assets/img/bgimage.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```
.bg-image{
        background-image: url('/assets/imgs/bgimage.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 200%;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        position: absolute;
```

Comment: Nope it didn't work. Till Yesterday it was working super fine. And today suddenly facing an error for all pngs that ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: use chrome inspect to check your file path in your APK.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me.

- Add your images in `src/assets/imgs` directory
- Set following in your scss file

```
    background-image: url("build/assets/imgs/bgimage.png");
```